# get chrome notifications text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

so i'm trying to create notification with button, and whenever this button will be clicked, an `alert()` with the notification text will pop.
iv'e got no success doing this, and this is where i got stuck:

```
var x = setInterval(function() 
{


    //Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    clearInterval(x);

    var abc = httpGet();
    chrome.notifications.create(now.toString(), {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: 'icon.png',
    title: 'Web Alert!',
     buttons: [{
        title: "click here to pop this notification text",
        iconUrl: "icon_128.png"
    }],
    message: "this is the text"
    });




 }, 5000);
```

Comment: so where is the click code?

Comment: @epascarello as i said, iv'e got no success doing this. i know how to create an `alert()` with JS. but i don't know how can i extract the text from the send notification.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.... and by the sign of no other activity it appears no one else understands either.  So you are asking is when they click on the button inside the chrome notification, than you want to do some action?

Comment: @epascarello i will edit my question. but i want to do this: when a notification will pop, i want to be able to press on the button of it, and when i do, a popup will apear (using JS `alert()`) and print to the screen the notification text